# ExtJS Ext.tree.Panel slow rendered on repeated store load

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a tree panel, data provided by remote service and I update my tree data by node. On first node data load all rendered relatively fast, but if I reload node data child nodes rendered too slowly. This becomes critical with large amount of child elements (1000+).

I use ExtJS 4.2.0.663.

As I understand its a bug in ExtJS - [related sencha forum thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257966-Ext-4.2.0.489-VERY-slow-tree-grid-on-second-load-with-bufferedrenderer-plugin).

[Simple fiddle](http://goo.gl/W49obq) from linked forum thread to illustrate issue.

I'm trying to find a fix for my ExtJS version, but to no avail (at the moment I can not upgrade ExtJS).

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

*I guess I can try to compare code of related components in different versions and make changes to my ExtJS files, but it is a laborious task and perhaps some of you already know the solution to this problem.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with layout. as I get this solution must help you.

please try to call `treeComponent.suspendLayouts()` on `beforexpand` event  and `treeComponent.resumeLayouts(true)` on `afterexpand` event.

if it does not helps try global suspend mechanism:

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();
...
Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```

Comment: `beforexpand` and `afterexpand` relate to the tree panel, not its nodes. I guess you mean `beforeitemexpand` and `afteritemexpand`?

Comment: I mean before loading data try to suspend layout, and after loading data continue it. where you do this action is your choice. the main thing is to do suspend and continue layout before and after reload

Comment: I guess it wont work, if you read issue details in provided forum thread on data load ExtJS delete all child nodes one by one and each deletion fires layout update, so if I `resumeLayouts(true)`when data is loaded it wont prevent multiple layout updates as its not started yet. Anyway ill try your solution, thanks.

Comment: the main thing is "each deletion fires layout update", but if you suspend layout, deletion will not fire layout update, and deletion process will do thing much faster. well this is my opinion for this problem. I might be wrong or maybe not :))

Comment: Tried with `beforeload` / `load` tree events (tree node just not rendered at all) and with `beforeitemexpand` / `afteritemexpand` (it doesnt fire when I update my node), it doest help.

Comment: Last guess, "(tree node just not rendered at all)", try to call `doLayout()` on treepanel.

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic problem of the treepanel in Ext4. We using ExtJS on our company products and treepanels have extreme problems with large data coming as child nodes.

You can use the bufferedRenderer plugin on the treepanel to speed up the generation:

```
plugins: {
    ptype: 'bufferedrenderer'
}
```

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qczvjrko/5/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try. Btw, is this issue fixed in ExtJS 5+?