# ExtJS4.2 Ext.tree.Panel slow rendered and error occured using plugin bufferrender

Tags: javascript, extjs, plugins

I have a tree panel, data provided by remote service and I update my tree data by node. On root node data load all rendered relatively fast, but if I reload node data child nodes rendered too slowly. This becomes critical with large amount of child elements (1000+). It spend 12 seconds finishing loading all the nodes.

I try bufferrender which takes less than 2 seconds, but I find it'll indicate

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of null".

error when I drag the scroll bar fast from bottom to top. Any solutions about this problem?

I found a similar question: `http://stackoverflow.com/q/35747961/6503345`

Here's a [tree panel](http://jsfiddle.net/qczvjrko/5/) example taking use of bufferrender. Drag the scroll bar fast from bottom to top will show the error!

Comment: Which version of ExtJS do you use?

Comment: I'm using Extjs4.2......

Comment: ExtJS 5 and especially 6 did a great job speeding up grid rendering.

Comment: We faced the similar issue. We removed bufferrender because it was of little help especially working with extjs version like 4.2. We rather went for pagination and did custom implementation on treepanel and showed only limited nodes.

Comment: We need to take a free version of extjs. And the treepanel with bufferrender is rendered fast except the error that I drag the scroll bar fast from bottom to top. So I want to know if anything help to fix this error.

please click here [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qczvjrko/5/)